# Issue in captured image always open in landscape mode custom camera in android

Tags: android, android-camera, surfaceview, landscape-portrait

i want to set my captured image in surfaceview in portrait mode so below is my code

**Saving Captured Image**

```
private String imgPathHacked = "";

PictureCallback jpegCallback = new PictureCallback() {
public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
FileOutputStream outStream = null;
long time = 0;
try {

time =  System.currentTimeMillis();

FileUtility fileUtility = new FileUtility();


File file = new File(fileUtility.getDirectoryName(NumericPassActivity.this)+Constans.HACK_ATTEMPT_URI);
if(!file.exists()){
 file.mkdirs();
}

File dataFile = new File(file.getAbsolutePath(),String.format("%d.jpg", System.currentTimeMillis()));
if(!dataFile.exists()){
 dataFile.createNewFile();
}



Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(dataFile.getAbsoluteFile());
camera.setDisplayOrientation(getCameraPhotoOrientation(NumericPassActivity.this, uri , dataFile.getAbsolutePath()));




outStream = new FileOutputStream(dataFile);    
outStream.write(data);
outStream.close();


imgPathHacked = dataFile.getAbsolutePath();




Utility utility = new Utility();
HackAttemptModel model = new HackAttemptModel();
model.setmAttemptedFor("Wrong PIN");
model.setmAttemptedPass(pass);
model.setmHackedImg(imgPathHacked);
utility.saveAttempt(model);


if(preview!=null && preview.camera!=null){
 preview.camera.startPreview();
 fr.removeAllViews();
 fr.addView(preview);
}



 } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
 e.printStackTrace();
 } catch (IOException e) {
 e.printStackTrace();
 } finally {



  }
 Log.d(TAG, "onPictureTaken - jpeg");
}
```

};

**Preview.java**

```
package com.Zebracom.filesecurity.utility;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.hardware.Camera.PreviewCallback;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;

public class Preview extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
private static final String TAG = "Preview";

SurfaceHolder mHolder;
public Camera camera;

public Preview(Context context) {
super(context);


mHolder = getHolder();
mHolder.addCallback(this);
mHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
 }

public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {

camera = Camera.open(Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT);



try {


  parm.setPictureSize(150, 150);
  parm.setPreviewSize(150, 150);
  parm.set("orientation", "portrait");
  camera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
  camera.setParameters(parm);*/

  camera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
  Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();
  List<Camera.Size> previewSizes = parameters.getSupportedPreviewSizes();
  Camera.Size previewSize = previewSizes.get(o);
  parameters.setPreviewSize(previewSize.width, previewSize.height);
  //parameters.setRotation(90);
  //parameters.set("orientation", "portrait");
  parameters.setPreviewSize(previewSize.width, previewSize.height);
  camera.setParameters(parameters);

  camera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);


  camera.setPreviewCallback(new PreviewCallback() {

  public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera arg1) {
  FileOutputStream outStream = null;
  try {
  /*File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/camera/");
                 if(!file.exists()){
                  file.mkdirs();
                 }

                 File dataFile = new File(file.getAbsolutePath(),String.format("%d.jpg", System.currentTimeMillis()));
                 if(!dataFile.exists()){
                  dataFile.createNewFile();
                 }

                    outStream = new FileOutputStream(dataFile);    
                    outStream.write(data);
                    outStream.close();*/
  Log.d(TAG, "onPreviewFrame - wrote bytes: " + data.length);
 } catch (Exception e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
 } finally {
 }
 Preview.this.invalidate();
   }
  });
  } catch (IOException e) {
 Log.e(TAG, "surfaceCreated >> "+e.toString());
  }
 }

  public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {

  this.getHolder().removeCallback(this);
  camera.stopPreview();
  camera.release();
  camera = null;
  }

 public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int w, int h)     {

 camera.startPreview();
}

 @Override
 public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
 super.draw(canvas);
 Paint p= new Paint(Color.RED);
 Log.d(TAG,"draw");
 canvas.drawText("PREVIEW", canvas.getWidth()/2, canvas.getHeight()/2, p );
 }
}
```

when i run above code my captured image always set in landscape mode but i want it in **portrait** so any idea how can i solve this problem ? your all suggestion are appreciable .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you use something like this?

To call the camera intent use this on button click:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            File f = new File(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "temp.jpg");
            intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(f));
            ((Activity) context).startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
```

and in activity that had the canvas use this method:

```
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        final ImageView uploadArea = (ImageView) attachmentDialog.findViewById(R.id.uploadArea);
        final EditText attachmentTitle = (EditText) attachmentDialog.findViewById(R.id.txtEditTitleAttach);
        Bitmap bitmap;
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            if (requestCode == Constants.REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE) {

                File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString());
                for (File temp : f.listFiles()) {
                    if (temp.getName().equals("temp.jpg")) {
                        f = temp;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                try {
                    BitmapFactory.Options bitmapOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();

                    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(f.getAbsolutePath(),
                            bitmapOptions);

                    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();

                    matrix.postRotate(-90);

                    Bitmap rotatedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), matrix, true);
                    ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    rotatedBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, byteArrayOutputStream);
                    byte[] attachmentBytes = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();

                    attachmentData = Base64.encodeToString(attachmentBytes, Base64.DEFAULT);


                    uploadArea.setImageBitmap(rotatedBitmap);
                    attachmentTitle.setText("temp.jpeg");

                    String path = android.os.Environment
                            .getExternalStorageDirectory()
                            + File.separator
                            + "CTSTemp" + File.separator + "default";
                    f.delete();
                    OutputStream outFile = null;
                    File file = new File(path, String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()) + ".jpg");
                    try {
                        outFile = new FileOutputStream(file);
                        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 85, outFile);
                        outFile.flush();
                        outFile.close();
                    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
}
}
```

I hope this will help:
In the above code I rotate the captured image using these 3 lines:

```
Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
matrix.postRotate(-90);
Bitmap rotatedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), matrix, true);
```